# Probability distribution function with risk parameter

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I'm looking for a way to adjust the probability distribution of a uniform random function I'm using in a program.

I need to find a discrete probability distribution that accepts a "*risk-aversion parameter*" *`z`* (ranging from `0 = neutral` to `5 = risk averse`) and changes how uniform the distribution is given an *upper* and *lower bound*, *`u`* and *`l`*, for each discrete interval in question, i.e. results in a *weight* *`p`* based on the parameter *`z`*.

For instance, consider a sample space discretized to only *`y`* intervals (originally a continuous space of intervals from the `0th` to the `100th` percentile).

When *`z`*`= 0`, the *weights* are simply the differecnes between the *upper* and *lower bounds* of the respective intervals chosen, i.e. *`p`*`=`*`u`*`-`*`l`*. However, as *`z`* increases, progressively more *weight* is given to higher-percentile intervals.

```
 Example of 7 intervals and their lower and upper bounds:

    interval    lower bound    upper bound
       10            0            20
       30           20            40
       50           40            60
       70           60            77.5
       85           77.5          90
       95           90            97
       99           97           120
```

How do I come up with a probability (*weight*) distribution function, which allows for such an adjustment.